# Remove "Comment" column in all post-types

Tags: comments, wp-admin, columns, post-type

I just want to remove **Comment's column** in **all post-types** and in a **single function**

[image]

**My current function , Have to do each post-type like this :**

```
function remove_post_columns($columns) {
    unset($columns['comments']);
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-post_columns','remove_post_columns',10,1);

function remove_page_columns($columns) {
    unset($columns['comments']);
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-page_columns','remove_page_columns',10,1);
```

**Possible to do in a single function** and for future post-types ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I got an alternative :**

*This will not just hiding but disabling also*

```
function disable_comments() {
    $post_types = get_post_types();
    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        if(post_type_supports($post_type,'comments')) {
            remove_post_type_support($post_type,'comments');
            remove_post_type_support($post_type,'trackbacks');
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_init','disable_comments');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change `manage_edit-post_columns` to `manage_posts_columns` in your code snippet, then it should hide the *comment* column for all post types (appart from the `page` post type) within the `WP_Posts_List_Table` <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/04319a7898343be862034ae61f2428a78d57bb8e/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L593)</sup>. You might want to check if the `column` array key isset first, before unsetting it.